# Unable to create a record in Azure Cosmos Db[NOSQL API] using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a record in Azure Cosmos DB[NOSQL API] using PowerShell, but Im getting some or the other error and fails every time.

Can someone let me know what I'm missing in this?

```
#region param
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[string]$resourceGroup = "rg_name",

[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[string]$cosmosAccount = "test",

[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[string]$database = "Testing",

[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[string]$CollectionId = "testcontainer"
)
#endregion param

Function InsterCosmosDbRecord
{
 $clientId       = "{client_id}"
 $clientSecret   = "{client_secret}"
 $tenantId       = "{tenant_id}"
 $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clientSecret - 
 AsPlainText -Force

  $credential     = New-Object -TypeName 
  System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientId, 
  $securePassword
  Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant 
  $tenantId

    $module = Get-InstalledModule -Name 'CosmosDB'

    if($module -ne $null)
    {
    write-host "module CosmosDB available"
     }
    else
    {
    write-host "module CosmosDB not available download in progress"
    Install-Module -Name CosmosDB -RequiredVersion 4.7.0 - 
    AllowClobber -force
    }
    
    $id = $([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())
    
    $document = @"
    {
        "id": $id,
        "productName": "widget-211",
        "key": "211"
    }
  "@
  $cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosAccount - 
  Database $database -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup
  
  $partitionkey = "/id"
  write-host "Document: "  $document
  New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 
  $CollectionId -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey $partitionkey
   
  }

  InsterCosmosDbRecord
```

I have replaced the image with the code. thanks for reminding me.
I have added the PartitionKey parameter, but now I'm facing a different error.

Let me know if there is anything that im missing.

Comment: Please edit the question and replace the picture of the code as proper code format so that it makes it easier to cut paste the code from stackoverflow. Makes it easier for everyone to reproduce your error rather than expecting us to retype all the code from scratch.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Aside from needing properly-formatted text: Please be mindful of tagging. For example: [tag:cosmos] has nothing to do with Cosmos DB (and the tag description explicitly calls this out)

Comment: Can you let us know what is the actual error message you're receiving?